# Algebraic sum of relative commutants in a finite von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(M,\tau)$ be a finite von Neumann algebra with faithful normal tracial state $\tau$.  Suppose that $A \subset M$ is a finite-dimensional abelian unital subalgebra--say $A = W^*(p_1,\dots, p_n)$ where $p_1,\cdots, p_n \in M$ are mutually orthogonal projections with sum $1_M$--and $N \subset M$ is an arbitrary unital ($1_N = 1_M$) von Neumann subalgebra.  Consider the relative commutants $A'\cap M$ and $N'\cap M$ and their respective $||\cdot||_2$-closures $\overline{A'\cap M}, \overline{N'\cap M} \subset L^2(M,\tau)$.

**Under what conditions is the *algebraic* sum $\overline{A'\cap M} + \overline{N'\cap M}$ a closed linear subspace of $L^2(M,\tau)$?**

Note: When $M$ is finite dimensional this sum is always closed. Also, recall that $A'\cap M = \sum_{i=1}^n p_iMp_i$.

Some references to consider are the following.

1. Deutsch, Frank. The angle between subspaces of a Hilbert space. (English summary) Approximation theory, wavelets and applications (Maratea, 1994), 107–130, NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci., 454, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1995. MathSciNet: [MR1340886](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1340886)
2. Luxemburg, W. A. J. A note on the sum of two closed linear subspaces.
   Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Indag. Math. 47 (1985), no. 2, 235–242. MathSciNet: [MR0799084](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0799084)

In [1], it is shown that two closed linear subspaces of a Hilbert space have a closed algebraic sum if and only if the cosine of the Friedrichs angle between them is strictly less than 1 (cf. Theorem 13). So an alternative approach to this question would be to compute the Friedrichs angle between these two relative commutant subspaces.

Reference [2] gives a number of functional analytic results on how to determine when the algebraic sum of two closed linear subspaces of a Banach space is closed.

**Special case: A good start would be to resolve this question in the case where $N = uAu^*$ for a unitary $u \in M$.**